# In Flask how can I use the secure session to authenticate user with curl?

Tags: python, rest, curl, flask

I am building a RESTful application with Flask which will use sessions to track the logged in user. Here is the login code which I adapted from this [Flask tutorial](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/wiki/Large-app-how-to#first-view)

```
@mod.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
  user = User.query.filter_by(email=request.json['email']).first()
  # we use werkzeug to validate user's password
  if user and check_password_hash(user.password, request.json['password']):
    # the session can't be modified as it's signed, 
    # it's a safe place to store the user id
    session['user_id'] = user.id
    resp = jsonify({'status':'authenticated'})
  else:
    resp = jsonify({'status':'Invalid usernam/password'})
    resp.status_code = 401
  return resp
```

When a user first logs in, I store their userid in the session, so that when the same user requests a resource, the data is tailored to them:

```
@mod.route('/address/')
@requires_login
def user_data():
  user = User.query.filter_by(id=session['usr_id']).first
  resp = jsonify(user.address)
  return resp
```

If I issue this command after logging in:

```
curl http://localhost:5000/address/
```

I receive:

```
{"status": 401, "message": "Unauthorized"}
```

instead of the address information for my logged in user.
Can anyone tell me how I can use the session in subsequent curl calls to return data that is specific to the userid stored in the cookie?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The response to your login request will contain a `Set-Cookie` header looking something like this:

```
Set-Cookie:session=<encoded session>; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

You need to send that cookie with your curl request so that the session data is available for processing, you can add additional headers to curl requests with `-H`, or specify the cookie explicitly:

```
curl --cookie "session=<encoded session>" http://localhost:5000/address/
```

Browsers will handle this for you of course, but curl is totally stateless and wont parse and store the `Set-Cookie` header for you by default, though if you're performing the login using curl, you can tell it to store the cookie in a cookie jar with `-c <file>`, and then you can read from it on your next request with `-b file`

[HTTP Cookie wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie)

[Curl cookie docs](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html)

[Curl man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)